# C - segmentation fault when comparing integers

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

here is a part of my code. When I run my code, it's requesting an input from user and then matching it with another integer which recorded in my structure. When user input is matching, it is working correct. But when user enters a wrong input, it gives a segmentation fault. In where, I should make changes on my code?

```
long int userInput,endCheck; // Input from user
int flag=0; // check for match
int status;
int c; // controlling ctrl+D
int position= 999; // position of where the user input and data matched

LABEL:
    printf("\n\t---------------------------------------\n");


    printf("\n\nPlease enter the student ID which you want to find(3-times CTRL+D for finish):\n");



   scanf("%d",&userInput);

   if( (c=getchar()) == EOF){
     exit(0);
     }




    for(i=0;i<lines,flag==0;i++){

       if(index[i].id == userInput){
          position=i;
          flag=1;
       }else{
          position=999;
        }
    }

    if(flag==0){
    printf("id not found");
    }


 studentInfo info; // for storing the information which we will take between determined offsets
    if(position!= 999){
           if ( (pos = lseek(mainFile,index[position].offset , SEEK_SET)) == -1)/*going to determined offset and setting it as starting offset*/
        { perror("classlist"); return 4; }


            while ( (ret= read(mainFile,&info, sizeof(info))) > 0  ){
           printf("\n\nStudent ID: %d, Student Name: %s\n\n",info.id,info.name);
                   break;// to not take another students' informations.
            }

   }
flag=0; 
goto LABEL;


printf("Program is terminated");
```

Comment: What is `index`?

Comment: What line has the segfault? What is the 'wrong input' you refer to? Why are you using gotos? WHY ARE YOU USING GOTOs?

Comment: index is my structure. In my structure I have an student ID and I am trying to match it with user's input.

Comment: scanf("%d",&userInput); should be scanf("%ld",&userInput); because userInput is a long. WHY ARE YOU USING GOTOs? My chest hurts.

Comment: I don't have time to create logic without using goto right now, I need only a quick solution for this problem. after scanf() I put a printf statement and even it didnt print out when I entered a wrong input( which will not match with recorded information in structure).

Comment: "I don't have time to create logic without using goto right now," -- YES, YOU DO.

Comment: @nicomp, %ld didnt' solve the problem I am still taking segmentation fault

Comment: @nicocomp, dude believe me I don't have time I must send this assignment in minutes

Comment: I didn't say it would solve the problem. I just said you needed to fix it.

Comment: what is the input which lead to seg fault and what is the recorded info?

Comment: Please let me know your grade when you turn in poorly formatted code with gotos . I am sincerely interested in how good your teacher is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it's incomplete and probably missing essential info, so you expect readers to guess what your other code is doing and why it doesn't work. _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve)."_

Comment: I vote to leave it open as a cautionary tale.

Comment: @xing Good spot. I wonder what was _expected_ there.

Comment: @xing, you are the man! It fixed my problem...

Comment: Programming isn't for you..leave it

Comment: @martin Grow some patience. Everyone needs encouragement, not negativity.

Answer (score 0):

The reason can be the fact that you are reaching an index that doesn't exist in the end of cycle, in the moment of the "if" statement with iterator "i".

Or in the last if, where you access a "position" index of the array. Check those limits.

Also, try [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), is useful for solving this kind of problems.

Comment: "Probably" is not suitable for an answer. This should be posted as a comment, which you can do when you have enough reputation.

Comment: So, to reach higher reputation I should help as I can. If I cannot comment, what do I do instead of answering?

Comment: If you cannot give a proper answer, then find another question where you can. I know it is a bit frustrating in the beginning, but that's the way it is.

Comment: @kutt I don't think how can someone answer to this with absolute certain, because the question is incomplete. I say "probably" not because I'm a noob, but because I'm not a magician to know what is actually happening in the code

Comment: The question is flagged for that and will likely be removed. If the question is not answerable it's pretty easy. Don't answer it. When you want clarifications you use comments. But not having enough reputation is NEVER an excuse for posting a comment as an answer. Don't get me wrong. I did that mistake myself in the beginning, and it is understandable. Besides, I'm not the one in charge. I'm just telling you that if you do like this, people will downvote and flag you. So find questions that you are capable of answering and then answer them. That's the only advice I can give.

Comment: Take a look here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do that loop with the unwanted comma is like this. When you find the right `index[i].id` you can exit the loop early by using `break`.

```
for(i=0;i<lines;i++){
    if(index[i].id == userInput){
        position=i;
        flag=1;
        break;
    }
}
```

You don't need the else branch as `position` is set to 999 from the outset of the code. But really you shouldn't use position in this fashion. What if you have more than 999 records? You're already using `flag` to identify if you've set `position` to a valid value. You should replace any instance of `if(position!= 999)` with `if(flag)`.

Or since `position` is a signed `int`, you could use a negative value and ditch the `flag`.